# side by side plots on multiple pages

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a list of plots for each categorical value in my data frame. For each category, 2 plots side by side will be plotted on one page and on each page will contain the plots for each category.

Each one of the tasks is doable but I'm having problems with combining both.

1- The task of creating plots by categories (one on each page of the PDF) can be easily done using this `dplyr` code:

```
AllPlots <- dataf %>% 
  group_by(category) %>% 
  do(plots=ggplot(data=., aes(x = x, y = val)) +  geom_bar(stat="identity")+ ggtitle(unique(.$category)))

pdf("plots.pdf")
invisible(lapply(AllPlots$plot, print))
dev.off()
```

2- The task of plotting side by side is also easy with `grid` and `gridExtra`:

```
p1 = qplot(1:10, rnorm(10))
p2 = qplot(1:10, rnorm(10))
grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol = 2, main = "Main title")
```

One can make a for loop based on the category and make the arrangement of the plots side by side and then combine them all in one page. however, I guess this slow since my dataframes are quite big.

The question is, how to do both things at the same time in a fast way?

Comment: Have you tried `facet_grid(.~category)`? Please add some reproducible data using e.g. `dput()` for more help.

Comment: `grid.arrange(grobs = AllPlots$plot, ncol = 2)` or `?marrangeGrob` if you need multiple pages. It won't be fast, but the bottleneck is ggplot/grid so there isn't much one can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I wanted only to comment, but because I'm new, the site doesn't let me to comment yet.

If you can plot by categories, try using this before starting to plot-

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
```

which will change your environment definitions, and will put 2 plots in each page one next to the other.

to find more about par(mfrow), you can look here-
http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html